# Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption

Tags: floats, hyperref

I get the following error:

```
 <use myfile.jpg>
 Package hyperref Info: bookmark level for unknown myfig defaults to 0 on input 
 ! Package hypcap Error: You have forgotten to use \caption.
```

for the following document (see  definition of myfig)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\begin{document}

\floatstyle{ruled} 
\newfloat{myfig}{thp}{lop} 
\floatname{myfig}{Text}
\hypcapredef{myfig}
\begin{myfig} \capstart
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{myfile} 
\caption{myBook}
\end{myfig}

\end{document}
```

the final .dvi and .pdf output are ok, but I need to avoid any error to edit by lyx.
I have seen a few posts on similar issues, but I am not sure how to fix things with my example.
thks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm afraid `hypcap` is incompatible with `float`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use package `caption`. It also implements the function of `hypcap`, thus
you do not need `\hypcapredef` and `\capstart`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\ref{fig:myfig}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{myfig}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{myfig}{Text}

\begin{myfig}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{myfile}
\caption{myBook}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{myfig}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry for late accept